Deriving the number operator in a Cooper Pair Box (CPB)
The details of my question follows closely from this source (pg 10 - 12): https://clerkgroup.uchicago.edu/PDFfiles/0210247.pdf
The standard CPB hamiltonian in charge basis is written as
$$
H = 4E_{c}\sum_{n}(n - n_{g})^{2} - \frac{E_{J}}{2}\sum_{n}\left(|n+1\rangle \langle n| + |n\rangle \langle n+1|\right)
$$
which can then be rewritten as a two-level system where
$$
H=
  \frac{1}{2}\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -E_{el} & -E_{J} \\
   -E_{J} & E_{el} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
where $E_{el} = 4E_{c}(1 - 2n_{g})$. The matrix can then be further simplified as
$$
H = -\frac{E_{el}}{2}\sigma_{z} - \frac{E_{J}}{2}\sigma_{x}
$$
where $\sigma_{z},\,\sigma_{x}$ are the pauli $z$ and $x$ matrix respectively. The preceding expression now looks like an NMR hamiltonian.
So this is my question: As mentioned on pg 11 - 12 of the source article, it says that a measurement of charge $(\hat{n})$ is equivalent to projecting the state on the z-axis, $\hat{n} = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \sigma_{z})$. How do I see this and how can I derive this?
Thank you.

The cooper pair number basis is identified with the $Z$ basis in the subspace of the two-level system $\{|n = 0\rangle, | n = 1 \rangle\}$. Measuring in the number basis is equivalent to a $Z$ basis measurement by definition. The spectrum of any generalized Pauli, $S$, is $\pm 1$ with an equal number of each sign. Measuring $S$ yields one of these eigenvalues, which is a projection onto the associated eigenspace, generally expressable as:
$$ P^{\pm}_S = \frac{1}{2}(1 \pm S) $$
This just comes from the fact that eigenstates for $P_S^{\pm}$ are those of $S$. In the basis where $S$ is diagonal, the $-1 \ (+1)$ diagonal terms vanish in the sum (difference) leaving only the sum of terms like $|\cdot\rangle\langle\cdot|$ where $\cdot$ is a +1 (-1) mutually orthonormal eigenstates.
The instance of $S = Z$ is a simple case.
